# inline UL for menu does not render background of parent element

Tags: html, css

The following is my HTML and CSS. The I'm expecting a nav bar with background color 4d4030 but not background is rendered. Anyone have nay ideas? Thanks!!

```
       <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Clients</li>
            </ul>
        </div>



#nav {
    background-color: #4d4030;  

}



#nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    float: left;  
}

#nav ul li{    
    display: inline;         
}

#nav ul li a{
    float: left; text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the float: left is hiding the parent div.  If you disable that then you will see the background color.

Comment: Add a "clearfix" to the parent: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your issue

```
#nav {
    background-color: #4d4030;  
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Gb22V/

Answer (score 0):

That's because you float the only child for the `nav` element which is the `ul` element. This makes the height of the `nav` element equal to 0. Clear your float by adding an `overflow: hidden` declaration (or using any other method to clear floats) to `nav` and it will work.

```
#nav {
    background-color: #4d4030;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4g5N/).

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
   <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About Us</li>
            <li>Clients</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.clear
{
   clear: both;
}
```